# My yaml is invalid in tag allow_failure using Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

In my yaml, i am trying to use the [`allow_failure:exit_codes:` feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failureexit_codes):

```yaml
job name:
 script:
   - ... 
 rules:
   - when: manual
 allow_failure:
   exit_codes: 
     - 1
     - 2
     - 3
```

GitLab mark `invalid yaml` in tag: `allow_failure:exit_codes`

In the documentation in gitlab, i found version history:

> Version history
> Introduced in GitLab 13.8.
> Feature flag removed in GitLab 13.9.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: The YAML you posted is valid and works for me. What version of GitLab are you using? Is that the **exact** yaml content you are using? You may have some typo or error somewhere else you are not showing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the feature was not removed. The _feature flag_ for the feature was removed in 13.9 (meaning the feature is enabled by default as of 13.9)

Comment: @sytech i check mi version and i'am using community edition 13.2.6. So this feature in this version is invalid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your GitLab version is 13.2.6 but the feature was introduced in GitLab 13.8, therefore you won't be able to use this feature unless you upgrade your GitLab instance to an applicable version.

As a possible alternative you can manually check error codes in your script. This works best if you run your script steps as a script run with bash (as opposed to directly in job steps).

With GitLab *Runner* version 13.12 or higher, you can use the `FF_USE_NEW_BASH_EVAL_STRATEGY` feature flag and have bash `trap`s work in inline steps... you can do something like this and not need to create a script file:

```yaml
MY_JOB:
  variables:
    FF_USE_NEW_BASH_EVAL_STRATEGY: "1"  # needed to make `trap` work with inline scripts
    # only available with GitLab runner 13.12+ 
    # It's usually OK to use runners at higher minor version than the GitLab server
  script:
    - | 
      cleanup() {
        rv=$?
        echo "return code was $rv"
        if [[ $rv -eq 3 ]]; then  # simulate behavior of `allow_failure:exit_codes:[3]`
            echo "return code ${rv} is allowed. Exiting 0"
            exit 0
        fi
        exit $rv
      }
    - trap "cleanup" EXIT
    - /bin/false || exit 3  # throw exit code 3
```